# Traverse recursive json tree and merge

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, recursion

I am trying to traverse through a recursive json tree as follow (json2) and merge with another json (json) if the identifier matches as follow. Do note that whenever **objects** is available, it may have **objects** or **object** but any how the identifier will be in same hierarchy of object.

Note: identifier value is always unique

I have walkthrough the underscore.js library but cant find any of the function that fit this requirement. In normal list case, findWhere would be sufficient to solve, but this is not the case as it has multiple level hierarchy.

JSON 2:

```
{
    "identifier1": "123456",
    "identifier2": "234567"
}
```

JSON 1:

```
{
    subtopic: [
        {
            "title": "title 1",
            "subtitle": "title 2",
            "objects": [{
                "title": "123"
                "label": "456"
                "objects": [
                    {
                        "identifier": "identifier1",
                        "object": {
                            "object-1": "123",
                            "object-2": "456"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "identifier": "identifier2",
                        "object": {
                            "object-1": "123",
                            "object-2": "456"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            ...
            ...
            Similar as above
        },
    ]
}
```

After merging

```
{
    subtopic: [
        {
            "title": "title 1",
            "subtitle": "title 2",
            "objects": [{
                "title": "123"
                "label": "456"
                "objects": [
                    {
                        "result": "123456",
                        "identifier": "identifier1",
                        "object": {
                            "object-1": "123",
                            "object-2": "456"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "result": "234567"
                        "identifier": "identifier2",
                        "object": {
                            "object-1": "123",
                            "object-2": "456"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            ...
            ...
            Similar as above
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you need some iteration and a recursive style for getting the right inner object for setting the new property.

```js
function merge(array, object) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        function iter(a) {
            if (a.identifier === k) {
                r = a;
                return true;
            }
            return Array.isArray(a.objects) && a.objects.some(iter);
        }

        var r;
        array.some(iter);                            
        if (r) {
            r.result = object[k];
        }
    });
}

var object2 = { "identifier1": "123456", "identifier2": "234567" },
    object1 = { subtopic: [{ "title": "title 1", "subtitle": "title 2", "objects": [{ "title": "123", "label": "456", "objects": [{ "identifier": "identifier1", "object": { "object-1": "123", "object-2": "456" } }, { "identifier": "identifier2", "object": { "object-1": "123", "object-2": "456" } }] }] }] };

merge(object1.subtopic, object2);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```